# Win XP Autohide feature not working when Eclipse is running

Tags: eclipse, windows-xp, taskbar

I am running Eclipse with Windows XP.  I have my desktop taskbar set to Autohide.  When I pull the mouse to the bottom of the screen the taskbar/Start menu pops up as expected EXCEPT when Eclipse is running.  When Eclipse is running, the only way to get the taskbar to pop up is to manually minimize all windows, then drag the mouse to the bottom of the screen in order get the task bar to pop up.  Had the problem with Eclipse Ganymede, then upgraded to Galileo - same problem.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Build id: 20100218-1602
(c) Copyright Eclipse contributors and others 2005, 2009.  All rights reserved.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just XP. This has been a running problem with Eclipse for a long time. See this bug going back to 2002: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24052.

To be fair, other applications have had this same issue, e.g. Firefox.